# XML Generation using XSD in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I have an XML file, i want to insert new data in it based on a schema defined in an XSD file, 
is there a way to do that in PHP?

Comment: I know nothing about XSD, but is [the non-standard SDO library](http://php.net/sdo-das-xml.examples) capable of doing what you're looking for?  It's one of only a handful of hits for "xsd" in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain a little more.  Are you attempting to add new nodes to the XML?  If so, you an use SimpleXMLElement::addChild.  If this is not what you mean, please give more details.